# closing a view from a controller and loading new view in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a login view and when the login is successfull, I want to close the view and load the new view. But I have having some trouble closing the view and loading the new one.

Here is my login.js view

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.login.Login',{
   extend:'Ext.window.Window',
    requires:[
    'MyApp.view.login.LoginController'
],

controller:'login',
xtype:'login-dialog',

autoShow:true,
width:360,
iconCls:'fa fa-key fa-lg',
title:'Login',
closeAction:'hide',
closable:false,
draggable:false,
resizable:false,
items: {
    xtype:'form',
    reference:'form',
    bodyPadding:15,
    defaultType:'textfield',
    defaults:{
        anchor:'100%',
        labelWidth:60,
        allowBlank:false,
        minLength:3,
        msgTarget:'under'
    },
    items:[{
        fieldLabel:'User',
        name:'user',
        vtype:'alphanum'
    },{
        fieldLabel:'Password',
        name:'password',
        inputType:'password'
    }],

    dockedItems:[{
        xtype:'toolbar',
        dock:'bottom',
        items:[{
            xtype:'tbfill'
        },{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'Cancel',
            iconCls:'fa fa-times fa-lg',
            listeners:{
                click: 'onButtonClickCancel'
            }
        },{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'Sign In',
            formBind:true,
            id: 'submit',
            iconCls:'fa fa-sign-in fa-lg',
            listeners:{
                click:'onButtonClickSubmit'
            }
        }]
    }]

}
```

});

And my controller LoginController.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.login.LoginController',{
  extend:'Ext.app.ViewController',
  alias:'controller.login',
onButtonClickSubmit: function(button, e, options){
    var me = this;
    if(me.lookupReference('form').isValid()){
        this.doLogin();
    }
},
doLogin: function(){
    var me = this.lookupReference('form');
    var user = me.down('textfield[name = user]').getValue();
    var password = me.down('textfield[name = password]').getValue();
    console.log('Username: ' + user);
    console.log('Password: ' + password);
    //var submitButton = Ext.getCmp('submit');
    me.getEl().mask('Authenticating.....', 'Loading');

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/extServlet/LoginController",
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            user: user,
            password: password
        },
        success: function(response){
            me.getEl().unmask();
            var dt = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            if (dt.isValid){
            //Ext.ComponentQuery.query('window')[1].close();
                this.getView().close()
    Ext.create('MyApp.view.main.Main');
            }
            else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'You are not authorised');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

});

Comment: Although *"having some trouble"* is very informative, can you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: After the successfull logn I want to close or hide the login window and replace it with new view. I can do it with ComponentQuery but going through the docs this.getView().close() should work but it is not working in my case.

Comment: And what exactly is happening? An error? If so, what's the error message?

Comment: I am getting uncaught refrence error that says this.getView() is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting uncaught refrence error that says this.getView() is not a
>   function

Scope problem. Specify scope on your AJAX request:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    // ...
    scope: this
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I am quite confused regarding the scope. Can u explain a bit.

Comment: Scope is what `this` points to. A very ABC thing in JavaScript. [Read more](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/).